# What errors could I possibly encounter with file I/O in C?

Tags: c, input, file-io, compiler-errors

I'm writing a program and it's going to include file I/O in C. I want to make it perfect. I understand that in C file I/O is error prone, unlike Java which catches exceptions. I want my program to handle all sorts of errors that could possibly occur but I realised I'm not sure of all the possibilities that could happen.

You could come across a file that has no contents in it, or if the disk is full you cannot read a file, or the contents may be incorrect etc... I was wondering if anyone could clearly outline other possibilities that I might encounter and how I could overcome them? It's much more difficult than Java which has exceptions. I basically want to handle my errors elegantly, but to do so I should know which errors I could expect.

Comment: You mean like `fopen` and friends? What's in the documentation that's unclear?

Comment: @CarlNorum yes basically i want to be able to handle all the errors that might occur when using functions related to fileIO for instance what if a user gives me the wrong file name etc

Comment: There are lot of documentations related to file operations like this - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html

Comment: it all depends what you want to do with the file, in C, checking the return values of runtime functions is key. so e.g. when opening a file with fopen, you check the return value and - depending on OS - you can then check what went wrong or simply use perror() to get a text description. C in that regard is not more complicated than Java, in fact it is simpler

Comment: An empty file is not an error.  You may not be able to write (more) data to a file if the file system is full, but that won't stop you from reading from a file.  Incorrect contents is a perpetual problem; however, the file format (text vs binary in particular) strongly affects the difficulties.  Most of the I/O functions return a success or failure value; check that return value scrupulously.

Comment: The errors you list are application specific, i.e. in some applications they are not errors, in others they might be.  So you need to decide at your design stage which errors are recoverable - any others need to be thoroughly reported, including error message and file name.

Comment: Every file I/O function I know has a return value, reporting about success which should be checked after call. Often, the reason for failing is reflected into an internal variable `errno` which can be evaluated also. (If `errno` is applicable, this should be mentioned in the doc. of the respective file I/O function including the error values `errno` may have and why.)